# Linear combinations of delta measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Let us consider the space of Borel, regular, complex measures on the real line, endowed with the total variation norm.
Inside this space, I would like to characterize the space of all the finite complex linear combinations of Delta measures. In particular, could we approximate a measure with compact support with linear combinations of that kind? Maybe it is possible only in the weak star topology...
Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You can also "just" apply Hahn-Banach. The dual space of $(C_0(\mathbb R)^*,w^*)$ is $C_0(\mathbb R)$. So, to prove that the linear combinations of Delta measures are $w^*$-dense it is enough to check that if a function $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ is such that $\int f d\delta_a=0$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$ then $f=0$; but this is obvious since $\int f d\delta_a=f(a)$.

Comment: this is even more nicier!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: This should word with $\mathbb{R}$ replaced by any locally-compact space no?

Answer (score 7):

Dirac measres are extreme points of the convex set of subprobability measures $P\subset C_0(\mathbb{R})^*$. This set is compact in the weak-$^*$ topology, so by Krein-Milman theorem every probability measure is a weak-$^*$ limit of finite convex combination of Dirac delta measures. For details see example 8.16 [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/simon_chp8.pdf).

Comment: The set of subprobability measures in $C_0(\mathbb{R})^*$ is weakly$^*$ compact; that of probability measures is not closed, $\delta_n \to 0$.

Comment: @yadaddy, Fixed