# Dirac measures are dense (Hahn-Banach theorem)

Tags: functional-analysis

In an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489658/linear-combinations-of-delta-measures), someone says without justification that the bidual of $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ with the weak topology is $C_0(\mathbb{R})$.

Similarly, in [this question on math overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131420/dirac-measures-dense-in-space-of-measures), the answer claims that the continuous linear forms on $\mathcal{M}(I)$ are given by $C(I)$.

But, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153494/the-space-c001-mathbbr-of-all-continuous-real-valued-functions-on), for example, it says that $C([0,1])$ is not reflexive.

How then are we applying the Hahn-Banach Theorem? Is there a nuance that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be careful about which topology you're using.  If you take ${\cal M}(I)$ **with the weak-* topology** as dual of $C(I)$, the continuous linear functionals on that are $C(I)$.  The non-reflexivity of $C(I)$ says that there are continuous linear functionals on ${\cal M}(I)$ **with the norm topology** that are not given by members of $C(I)$.  Such linear functionals are continuous with respect to the norm topology, but not with respect to the weak-* topology.  An example of such a functional is $f(\mu) = \mu(E)$ where $E$ is a nonempty proper Borel subset
of $I$.

As to the title, the linear span of Dirac measures is dense in ${\cal M}(I)$ with the weak-* topology, but not with the norm topology.

Comment: @AIM_BLB Actually yes, I believe I ended up citing 

K. Parthasarathy, Probability Measures on Metric Spaces. Probability and Mathematical Statistics, Elsevier Science, 1967.

pgs 44-46

Comment: Thanks Robert, this is a very interesting example.  As for the reference I found a version in Prokorov s paper :)